# Tikz: change shape size relative to text

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

So I want to draw a controlled-NOT gate:

```
\begin{circuitikz}[scale=.3,thick] \draw
(2,0) node[adder] (xor) {}
(0,2) node (x) {$x$}
(0,0) node (y) {$y$}
(4,2) node (xout) {}
(4,0) node (yout) {}
(2,2) node[inner sep=0pt,minimum size=3,circle,fill=red] (cxor) {}
(x.east) -- (xout.west)
(y.east) -- (xor.west)
(xor.east) -- (yout.west)
(xor.north) -- (cxor)
;
\end{circuitikz}
```

Problem is, the gate is huge and this is ugly.
I can reduce the size of the gate using `every node/.style={transform shape}` but this also reduces the size of the text. So I can either have (readable text + ugly big shapes) or (tiny text + correct shapes).

To scale down the shapes while keeping the text readable, I can add `transform shape` only to the shaped node — this seems to work, but 1) is there a way to put that in the `circuitikz` options instead?, and 2) this would also mess with any text entered inside the shaped node, right?

[image: Ugly diagram]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please expand the code snippet that you have posted to a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). It is much easier to help you if we can start with some compilable code that illustrates your problem. A MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, include any necessary packages and be as *small as possible* to demonstrate your problem. At the moment we have to guess what you are doing because we cannot reproduce your problem from the code that you have given us.

Comment: All ciruitikz components are based on bipoles/length  use `\ctikzset{bipoles/length=.5cm}` for example.

Comment: @John Kormylo - this is a tripole, not a bipole, so there would be several lengths to change.

Comment: `scale` option of `circuitikz` image doesnt change size of elements. so your scale change distances  and not node `adder`. consequently it seems "magnified".  see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

ALL Circuitikz components are based on bipoles/length, also known as `\pgf@circ@Rlen`.  The components dimensions are scale factors applied to this basic distance.  Obviously this practice started with bipoles and got extended to tripoles, monopoles and other components.

[image: demo]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\ctikzset{bipoles/length=.5cm}
\begin{circuitikz}[scale=.3,thick] \draw
(2,0) node[adder] (xor) {}
(0,2) node (x) {$x$}
(0,0) node (y) {$y$}
(4,2) node (xout) {}
(4,0) node (yout) {}
(2,2) node[inner sep=0pt,minimum size=3,circle,fill=red] (cxor) {}
(x.east) -- (xout.west)
(y.east) -- (xor.west)
(xor.east) -- (yout.west)
(xor.north) -- (cxor)
;
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

- in drawing of `circuitikz` image is sensible use a way of drawing, as is supposed by `circuitikz` packages
- scaling of `ciruitikz` pictures is not good idea, better is draw it in smaller size from beginning
- for example consider that you like to reduce image size to half (obtained by scale=0.5), the the equivalent image code without scaling is:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}% used default thick of lines
\ctikzset{bipoles/length=5mm}% reduced size of bipoles
\draw   (1,0)    node[adder] (xor) {}
\draw   ( 0.5,0) node[adder] (xor) {}
        ( 0,0)   node[left]  {$y$} -- (xor.west)
        (xor.east) -- (1,0)
        ( 0,1)   node[left]  {$x$} to [short] (1,1)
        (.5,1)   to [short,color=red,*-]  (xor.north);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**addendum:**
if for some reason you like had to use `scale` option in your images, than you had to scale also the node `adder`:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[scale=0.3]
\draw   (1,0) node[scale=0.3,adder] (xor) {}% observe "scale" option in node
        (0,0)   node[left]  {$y$} -- (xor.west)
        (xor.east) -- (2,0)
        (0,2)   node[left]  {$x$} to [short] (2,2)
        (1,2)   to [short,color=red,*-]  (xor.north);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]